# How to make a TableView Column as LocalDate and set it's value only via FXML?

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml, tablecolumn

How can I fill LocalDate values to a column in fxml only?

Somewhere in my Controller class:

```
protected void addPerson(ActionEvent event) {       
    ObservableList<Person> data = tableView.getItems();
    data.add(new Person(firstNameField.getText(),lastNameField.getText(),emailField.getText(),checkBox.isSelected(),Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText()),LocalDate.now()));     
    firstNameField.setText("");
    lastNameField.setText("");
    emailField.setText("");
    checkBox.setSelected(false);
    numberField.setText("0");
    dateField.setText(""+LocalDate.now());

}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person {

private final SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleBooleanProperty checked = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
private final SimpleIntegerProperty alter = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;
```

...

FXML: ...

```
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Date">
        <cellValueFactory>
            <PropertyValueFactory property="date" />
        </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="G" />
</columns>
<items>

    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
         <Person alter="1" checked="false"  
                 email="tester1.test@test.com"  firstName="Tester1"   
                 lastName="Test"/>                                                                      

    </FXCollections>
</items>
```

I tried:

```
<Person alter="1" checked="false" email="tester1.test@test.com" firstName="Tester1" lastName="Test" date="2016.01.01"/>
```

But I get a javafx.fxml.LoadException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce 2016.01.01 to class java.time.LocalDate.
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:496)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:258)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:54)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.applyProperty(FXMLLoader.java:512)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:363)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:325)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:235)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FXMLLoader` cannot initialize `LocalDate` from a `String` this leaves you with 2 options:

#### using `valueOf` + `fx:value`

Implement a method `public static LocalDate valueOf(String)` in some class

```
public final class Util {

    private Util() {
    }

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");

    public static LocalDate valueOf(String val) {
        return LocalDate.parse(val, DATE_FORMAT);
    }

    public static String toString(LocalDate date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.format(DATE_FORMAT);
    }

}
```

and change your fxml file like this:

```xml
<Person alter="1" checked="false" email="tester1.test@test.com" firstName="Tester1" lastName="Test">
    <date>
        <Util fx:value="2016.01.01"/>
    </date>
</Person>
```

#### using a `BuilderFactory`

Leave the fxml as it is and use a custom [`BuilderFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/BuilderFactory.html) that uses a [`Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Builder.html) to create `Person`s. This builder has getters/setters for every property of `Person` that delegate to the appropriate methods of the product except for those properties that require special handling. For those properties it additionally does a conversion to/from `String`.

```
public class PersonBuilder implements Builder<Person> {

    private final Person product = new Person();

    @Override
    public Person build() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setAlter(int value) {
        product.setAlter(value);
    }

    public void setDate(String value) {
        product.setDate(Util.valueOf(value));
    }

    public void setEmail(String value) {
        product.setEmail(value);
    }

    ...

    public int getAlter() {
        return product.getAlter();
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Util.toString(product.getDate());
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return product.getEmail();
    }

    ...

}
```

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("person.fxml"));
loader.setBuilderFactory(new BuilderFactory() {

    private final BuilderFactory fallback = new JavaFXBuilderFactory();

    @Override
    public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
        return type == Person.class ? new PersonBuilder() : fallback.getBuilder(type);
    }

});

loader.load();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However the date is not parsed correctly although your pattern is "yyyy.MM.dd" it shows "yyyy-MM-dd" when I run the application.

Comment: @7twenty7: I focused on reading the dates. How you display them is a different thing, but there already is the `Util.toString` method that is capable of converting a `LocalDate` object to a `String` formated the same way as the xml attribute.

Comment: I just don't understand why the format is then "yyyy-MM-dd". I mean... I already read the values in the fxml in right format "yyyy.MM.dd". Why would it show the values in "yyyy-MM-dd" ?

Comment: @7twenty7: The [`toString` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) uses the [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) formatting, you get that `String`. `LocalDate` does not keep information about the formatter used to parse it. This is the same for `int`: You can parse it from hexadecimal, octal or even binary, however that doesn't mean the program "remembers" the original format. e.g. `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("FF", 16));` prints `255`.

Comment: So what would be the way to show the values in the "yyyy.MM.dd" format without making a SimpleStringProperty of it? When I have Strings in the column I can't sort the dates correctly.

Comment: Use a custom `TableCell` for the column that displays the `LocalDate` in the correct format. You can assign the appropriate `cellFactory` in the fxml.